# How to do shell variable expansion in process substitution?

Tags: bash, process-substitution

I have a command like that in my script:

```bsh
regex="abba"
diff <(grep "${regex}" file1) file2
```

The problem is if I run the script with `bash script.sh` the `${regex}` variable doesn't get expanded. I can run the script differently - with `source script.sh`. This way the variable gets expanded. What's the deal and how to change the script so that it can be run?

I've also tested variations: `"$regex"`, `"${regex}"`, `$regex`.

There is `#!/bin/bash` incantation in the script.

Comment: How did you determine that it does not get expanded? Have you run the script with `bash -x` for example?

Comment: Oh, there is something I missed. I ran `zsh --verbose` that made me think it is not expanded. Now I think it simply shows command before expansion. 

`bash -x` shows expanded form. Nevertheless I get different outcome running commands one by one in shell than by running the script. 

Sorry for the ill-posed question. I will update you and possibly the question.